# Pinterest API search not working anymore

Tags: search, pinterest

I was looking for pinterest API endpoints...

I've founded some URL..

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/domains/<domains>/search/pins/?query=<query>&access_token=<access_token>
```

I was able to generate the access_token..but every time I've tried a POST on that URL it gave me:

```
{  
    "status":"failure",
    "code":12,
    "host":"ngapi2-b2fc674c",
    "generated_at":"Mon, 09 Feb 2015 17:45:29 +0000",
    "message":"Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that.",
    "data":"path: /v3/domains/www.vtracker.com.br/search/pins/\nparams:
            [('access_token', [u'blablahblahblah']), ('query', 
            [u'como'])]\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File 
            \"/mnt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py\", 
            line 1504, in wsgi_app\n    response = 
            self.full_dispatch_request()\n  File 
            \"/mnt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py\", 
            line 1264, in full_dispatch_request\n    rv = 
            self.handle_user_exception(e)\n  File 
            \"/mnt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py\", 
            line 1262, in full_dispatch_request\n    rv = 
            self.dispatch_request()\n  File 
            \"/mnt/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py\", 
            line 1248, in dispatch_request\n    return 
            self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)\n  File 
            \"../api/pin_api.py\", line 715, in __call__\n    
            self._perform_auth()\n  File \"../api/pin_api.py\", line 848, in 
            _perform_auth\n    authorization.perform(dictified_values, 
            request.cookies, request.headers)\n  File \"../api/pin_api.py\", 
            line 271, in perform\n    params, cookies, headers)\n  File 
            \"../api/pin_api.py\", line 121, in perform\n    headers=headers)\n  
            File \"../api/decorators.py\", line 212, in 
            verify_user_authorization\n    
            core.Consumer.manager.get_scope_as_int(required_scope)):\n  File 
            \"../core/managers/consumer_manager.py\", line 479, in 
            check_scope\n    scope = migrate_legacy_scope(scope)\n  File 
            \"../core/managers/consumer_manager.py\", line 475, in 
            migrate_legacy_scope\n    if ~scope & old == 0:\nTypeError: bad 
            operand type for unary ~: 'NoneType'\n"
}
```

Is Pinterest API v3 closed or some other problem is going on?

Thks

Answer (score 0):

You must first ensure that your app has been approved by Pinterest.  You may need to reapply for approval (I had to reapply for my app).  Once you are approved, you will see a link on your app page called "Visit API docs".  This will link to the V3 documentation (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/pinner_app).  At least, this is the documentation I have been given access to.  If you have a different type of app, maybe you will have access to other documentation.

After your app has been approved, the section of the documentation you will be interested in is "Search user pins" (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/pinner_app/#tag/search).

The endpoint is: [https://api.pinterest.com/v3/search/user_pins/{user}/](https://api.pinterest.com/v3/search/user_pins/%7Buser%7D/)

The documentation provides details about the query parameters that are allowed and the response data.